# Java pigServer relative path

Tags: java, path, apache-pig, relative-path

I want to use relative paths in a java program  working with pigServer. I would like to know if this code is correct:

```
String filePathDirectory="/consultaBicing1";
Path path=new Path(filePathDirectory);
hdfs.delete(path);
pigServer.store("source",path.toString());
```

The program fails in the instruction:

```
 pigServer.store("source",path.toString());
```

How can I use relative path in this code?